# Layout issues for horizontal ul with nested ul

Tags: html, css, layout

[JS Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/zw36fqeb/1)

I have a menu requiring a redesign included on multiple different sites, but with different items on each. It's not feasible to change the HTML on all sites, so I'm making CSS changes only but I'm struggling to get the new CSS to meet my requirements. The HTML consists of a `<ul>` and the child `<li>`s can have an `<ul>` of their own. I need:

1. The items in the menu to be displayed horizontally
2. If the selected menu item has a sub menu, this is displayed below, but aligned with the left side of the menu, not below the parent item
3. The container `div`'s height to match the height of its content

My issue is that to get the sub-menu to be left aligned I need to set position to absolute and left to 0 (or use float left). However, if I do either of these then `height: auto` on the parent element no longer includes the sub-menu. I can't set a fixed height as sometimes the sub-menu exists and sometimes it doesn't.

My fallback solution will probably use JavaScript, but I'd rather avoid that if possible.

```css
ul{
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding-left: 0;
}
    
li{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.2em;
}
    
.menu-container{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: auto;
}
    
.opened-menu span {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
    
.top-menu {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  width: 100%;
}
    
.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-container">
  <ul class="top-menu">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li class="opened-menu">
      <span>item 2</span>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>submenu 1</li>
        <li>submenu 1</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  Here is some more content
</div>
```

Comment: "*If the selected menu item has a sub menu, this is displayed below, but aligned with left of the menu*" - what defines when a menu is 'selected,' is it clicked on to become selected, or is it hovered-over? Can multiple menus/options be selected?

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica, there is js handling the menu functionality that will add a class for any menu clicked on. Only a single item can be selected meaning that only a single sub-menu will appear.